# General error: 1271 Illegal mix of collations for operation 'match'

Tags: mysql, schema, laravel-4, collation, vagrant

I have a Laravel 4 app running on a Vagrant box on my local machine, plus I also have the same app (using GitHub) on my live demo server.

Now, I have a search function that uses MATCH and AGAINST for fulltext searching. It works fine on the live demo server but on the local machine I get General error: 1271 Illegal mix of collations for operation 'match'.

I've tried everything I can find online to resolve this, I've checked the tables and database collation, as well as the columns themselves and they all match utf8_unicode_ci. The encoding is utf8.

I'm struggling to see why this would work on the live demo server but not on my local machine.

Database engine is MyISAM.

Can anyone help me out here. I'm really stuck on this one.

I have ran this query in SequalPro I found on the internet:

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name, character_set_name, collation_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE collation_name = 'utf8_general_ci'
ORDER BY table_schema, table_name,ordinal_position;
```

And found that the information_schema, mysql and performance_schema are all set to utf8_general_ci. How do I go about changing this please? What is the best way in Vagrant? Thanks.

**EDIT**: Just checked the live demo server uing the same query, and the information_schema there is also utf8_general_ci, while the mysql collation varies. So how can this be affecting it locally but not on the server. Points to something else to me.

**EDIT**: Even tried creating a new database and re-migrating but no joy. It must be something to do with the Vagrant setup.

Comment: OK, I've found the offending table. It is the 'notes' table, specifically the 'date' (DATE) and 'time' (TIME) columns. It seems to be getting set to 'latin1_swedish_ci'. Why would that be? Seems very odd to me.

Comment: This still doesn't explain why it works on the server though.

Comment: Simply a missconfiguration - your local enviro might fallback to `latin1_swedish_ci` if you do not specify otherwise.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. So do you know where in a Vagrant setup I would change the default fallback?